# how to truncate text in table-cell?

Tags: javascript, css, contenteditable

i want to make my table cell contenteditable like the one in excel (means when i click on any cell, a highlighted editable box should come and its width should grow if entered text exceeds the cell-width). when i am done, table cell should be displayed as a normal cell but exceeding text should truncate. It should be similar to excel sheet cell.

i have tried,

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="content" style="overflow:hidden"></td>
```

and on focus event i made its z-index:15. Also on blur event, i removed the z-index. But the text entered is not trimmed and cell width gets updated as that of text.

i also have tried,

```
<td><div contenteditable="true" style="width:100%; height:100% overflow:hidden"></div>  
</td>
```

but overflow not working.

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think you expecting like this try this

```
  .content{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and also try

```
   word-wrap: break-word;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

for breaking word.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/Ah6fb/54/)

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working on my browser (firefox), when i am entering the text, width of cell grows.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content:focus{
  display: inline-block;
  width: "YOUR WIDTH";
}
```

Now you should add question in javascript tag about : "how to make an edit in that cell"